# Java Observer and Observable not working properly between applications

Tags: java, observer-pattern, observable

I have an application with a main JFrame that contains a default list model. I want that if I modify something on these records, the second running application is automatically updated.

So far I have a MainController class which implements the listener and overwrites the update method:

```
public class MainController implements ActionListener, Observer {
  public void update(Observable o, Object o1) {}
}
```

and a simple class that extends Observable

```
public class Comanda extends Observable{}
```

My problem is that if I delete one record from the first application, the second list doesn't update. The program is deleting the record from the text file but is not updating the default list model.   Same problem with edit or add.

I tried adding "reloadList()" in the update method, but that doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: It'd be useful if you show your code for starting the notification of observers. (`Observer`/`Observable` really should have been deprecated in 1.1. I also would use anonymous inner classes rather than having a single class do multiple tasks.)

Comment: @rhose87: *"...to update the second running application"* [sic]...  You are running **two different Java applications** and expect the action that are happening in one application to be notified in the other!?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you called `addObserver` on `Comanda` and added the `MainController` as an `Observer`?  Also, when the change occurs are you calling `setChanged` and `notifyObservers`?

Looking at the code you have posted I can see that you have not wired the `Observer` and `Observable` Objects together.  As I said, you have to call `addObserver` on your `Observable` object, then within your `Observable` Object, whenever a change is made you need to call `setChanged` then `notifyObservers`.  Only when `notifyObservers` is called will the `update` method of any `Observer`s that have been added be called.

You said in your question that when you delete one record the list doesn't update, which makes me think that `Comanda` is probably not the `Object` that you want to `Observe`.  Whichever Object it is that holds the `List` of records is the one that should be the `Observable`.

Have a look at [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-1996/jw-10-howto.html) for some more information on the Observer/Observable pattern.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to to is called "interprocess communication" - sending data from one application to another. There are various ways to do it; a Google search would give you more information. `Observable` only works within a single application.